# Does Oracle Lite Database 10g support spatial data type?

Tags: oracle, spatial

Can't find any online documentation about the support data types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. See [Oracle® 10gR2 Spatial User's Guide and Reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14255/toc.htm)

Comment: That documentation is for the main database product; the Lite [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12095_01/nav/portal_booklist.htm) doesn't appear to include it. [This](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/options/spatial/spatial-techinfo-152816.html) also suggests not.